# Multiple Communities implementation

Tags: community, profile

I have two different communities c1 and c2.

I have one profile which is assigned to both the communities.
that means I can have different users for different communities but they will have only one profile.

Now I'm facing one issue in email communication.
Whenever I'm sending email from c2 community using merge field of communities like {!Community_Url}, it is sending the url of c1 community instead of c2 community.

This is one of the issue which I found, is there any other issue?

What is the best practice for communities? Do we really need to create two profile if there are issues with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is create separate profiles because if any of user are aware of both community URL then they can access both community. They might not get their relevant data but still they can access a lots of information

Apart from these if you want to make some objects available for one community then other community users can also access that(using URL hacks).

Also its hard to maintain users and two different profiles you can easily identify them based on there profile and can make separate groups or permission set for them.